# How to connect a container view to a childviewcontroller.view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, containers

On IOS 5.1 I have added a container view to a viewcontroller on storyboard. I want to connect that container view via `IBOutlet`, so I can manage it easily on IB.

I have tried to use a regular `UIView`:

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *leftView; //connected this to container view on interface builder
```

then, if I use this, it doesn't work

```
[self.leftView addSubview:tableVC.view];
```

If I add a childview controller programmatically  it works but it covers full screen of course.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    UITableViewController *tableVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogMasterViewController"];
    [self.view addSubview:tableVC.view];

    [self addChildViewController:tableVC];
    [tableVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

How can I connect container view to child view controller?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you retrieving the storyboard via `storyboardWithName` vs just `self.storyboard`? Are you changing storyboards? And when you tried to use `self.leftView`, can you confirm that it was not `nil`? I just tested your code, using `self.leftView` (and setting the frame, accordingly) and it works fine, so I'm trying to figure out what's going on here. And when you say "it doesn't work" when you use `leftView`, do I infer that you see absolutely nothing change on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the following and it works fine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    UITableViewController *tableVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogMasterViewController"];
    [self.leftView addSubview:tableVC.view];
    tableVC.view.frame = self.leftView.bounds;

    [self addChildViewController:tableVC];
    [tableVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

A couple of thoughts:

1. If your `LogMasterViewController` is not a `UITableViewController`, but rather a view controller with a `UITableView` on it, you might want to make sure that you don't have autolayout or autosizing constraints on that tableview that make it resize the tableview to something that you can no longer see.
2. You might want to run the app, pause it after the app has finished presenting the screen (I put a breakpoint in `viewDidAppear` ... anything after that point should also work too, but don't do `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`) with the `LogMasterViewController` in `self.leftView` and then type the following command in the debugger console:

   ```
   po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   ```

   You might want to give your `leftView` and the main view of `LogMasterViewController` unique tag numbers so you can more easily decipher the output. Anyway, use this `recursiveDescription` to identify whether the table view has been presented, but simply in a fashion so you cannot see the table, or whether it's not added at all. You can also confirm that your `leftView` (with its unique `tag` number, if you gave it one) is there, too.

   ```
   (lldb) po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
   $0 = 0x071a7a60 <UIWindow: 0x758e7a0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x75ab340>>
      | <UIView: 0x71a8480; frame = (0 20; 320 460); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a84e0>>
      |    | <UIView: 0x71a8ce0; frame = (0 0; 160 460); autoresize = TM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x71a8510>>
      |    |    | <UITableView: 0x7a9d400; frame = (0 0; 160 460); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; tag = 3; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71aba30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ab100>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71bbd50; frame = (0 396; 160 44); text = 'Row 10'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bbe80>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71bbeb0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71bc100>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bbf10>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71bc1e0; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 10'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bbd20>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bc5c0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bb560>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71bb5c0; frame = (0 352; 160 44); text = 'Row 9'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bb6f0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71bb720; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71bb970>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bb780>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71bba50; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 9'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bb590>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bc560; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bae50>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71baeb0; frame = (0 308; 160 44); text = 'Row 8'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bafe0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71bb010; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71bb260>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bb070>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71bb340; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 8'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bae80>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bc500; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba740>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71ba7a0; frame = (0 264; 160 44); text = 'Row 7'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba8d0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71ba900; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71bab50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba960>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71bac30; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 7'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba770>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bc4a0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba030>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71ba090; frame = (0 220; 160 44); text = 'Row 6'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba1c0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71ba1f0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71ba440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba250>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71ba520; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 6'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ba060>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71b8a70; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9910>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71b9970; frame = (0 176; 160 44); text = 'Row 5'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9aa0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71b9ad0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b9d20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9b30>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71b9e00; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 5'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9940>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71b8010; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9200>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71b9260; frame = (0 132; 160 44); text = 'Row 4'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9390>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71b93c0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b9610>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9420>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71b96f0; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 4'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9230>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bb4f0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8af0>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71b8b50; frame = (0 88; 160 44); text = 'Row 3'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8c80>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71b8cb0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b8f00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8d10>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71b8fe0; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 3'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8b20>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71bade0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8090>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71b80f0; frame = (0 44; 160 44); text = 'Row 2'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8220>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71b8250; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b85a0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b82b0>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71b8790; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 2'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b8630>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71ba6d0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b9fe0>>
      |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x71b4d30; frame = (0 0; 160 44); text = 'Row 1'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b4e80>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x71b4fb0; frame = (0 0; 160 43); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x71b5b80>; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b5040>>
      |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x71b65d0; frame = (10 0; 140 43); text = 'Row 1'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b66e0>>
      |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x71b98a0; frame = (0 43; 160 1); autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71bbca0>>
      |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x71ac5d0; frame = (0 453; 320 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ac700>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b3a90; frame = (0 483; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b3b10>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b3dd0; frame = (0 527; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b3e30>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b3e60; frame = (0 571; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b3ec0>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b3ef0; frame = (0 615; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b3f50>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b3f80; frame = (0 659; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b3fe0>>
      |    |    |    | <_UITableViewSeparatorView: 0x71b4030; frame = (0 703; 160 1); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x71b4090>>
      |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x71ac810; frame = (153 541; 7 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x71ac8b0>>
   ```

   In this example, I gave my main view of my root controller a `tag` of "1", `leftView` has a `tag` of "2", and the main view of `LogMasterViewController` has a `tag` of "3". In this case, these show up as the second, third, and fourth lines of my output (and I also see my `UITableViewCells` listed below).

Comment: thanks this works fine tableview is loaded on exact leftView size, `self.leftView` was  not nil but not displayed anything either I guess it was because I didn set `.frame` ?

Comment: @MordFustang That could be. I always set the initial frame for my first child. Subsequent `transitionFromViewController` (if you do that) will inherit it fine, but I always set the first frame. I usually have the problem that the child will exceed the frame of the container if I don't do that.